# Splitview content property windows universal

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, universal, splitview

Im including the splitview in my app. But **i dont know how to fill the content of my splitview**. I read i should nest the frame in there. So i have my Mainpage.xaml, and if the user clicks one menue button the content of the splitview should be for example helpandabout.xaml. Or **what should i nest in the content property? And how do i replace the content with different pages.** 
I currently just tried to change the visibility of grids if the user presses one button but thats not the philosophy behind this control.
Like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Visibility="Visible"> </Grid>
<Grid Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="Grid2"> </Grid>
```

And than the user presses a button at the splitview pane and the code does this:

```
Grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Grid2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

And i know thats a silly code piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can replace the complete App standard with an SplitView and Create Navigation etc.

What I did is the following:

1- Learn the Navigation Example from here:
[uwp navigation example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/XamlNavigation)

2.- After you learn how it works, it's  has some tricks like the commandbar is outside an appbar, etc. you can extract all the code in a library.

AppShell.xaml, NavMenuItem, NavMenuListView.cs, PageHeader.xaml

3.- Create the following extensions:

```
public class NavigationExtensions
{

public static void Initialize<T>(List<NavMenuItem> list, NavigationFailedEventHandler OnNavigationFailed, LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppShell shell = Window.Current.Content as AppShell;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (shell == null)
        {
            // Create a AppShell to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            shell = new AppShell();

            shell.NavigationList = list;

            try
            {
                shell.CurrentItem = list.First(i => i.DestPage == typeof(T));
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            // Set the default language
            shell.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            shell.AppFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }
        }

        // Place our app shell in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = shell;

        if (shell.AppFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored, navigate to the first page
            // suppressing the initial entrance animation.

            shell.AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(T), e.Arguments, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

}

4.- Reference all of this in your project and in the App.xaml.cs add

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationExtensions.Initialize<PersonalView>(Navigation.GetNavigationMenuItems(),OnNavigationFailed,e);
    }
```

where the method is for instance:

```
public class Navigation
{
    public static List<NavMenuItem> GetNavigationMenuItems()
    {
        var list = new List<NavMenuItem>(
        new[]
        {
            new NavMenuItem()
            {
                Symbol = Symbol.Contact,
                Label = "Personal",
                DestPage = typeof(PersonalView)
            },
            new NavMenuItem()
            {
                Symbol = Symbol.World,
                Label = "Countries",
                DestPage = typeof(CountriesView)
            },
            new NavMenuItem()
            {
                Symbol = Symbol.Setting,
                Label = "Settings",
                DestPage = typeof(SettingsView)
            },
        });

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  i was looking exactly for this kind of answer!

Comment: You're welcome, there are several good implementations in the example and to be up to date I encourage you to follow me